# What kind of code is used to build this web based interactive calculator?

Tags: html

I am interested in learning how to build an interactive calculator similar this one [keto-calculator](https://www.ruled.me/keto-calculator/), but I'm not sure where to start researching the process.

- What kind of code is something like this made with?
- Is this considered a calculator, interactive form or is it a different type
  of element?

Comment: link is not working for me, please fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was made using jQuery.

https://cdn1.ruled.me/wp-content/themes/genesis-child/js/ketocalculator.js

I would consider it both a calculator and an interactive form. It calculates results based on the user's inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Its implemented using Wordpress Themes and Basic HTML, CSS, Javascript and jQuery.

[image]